# scrollview covers up image view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

I am trying to make a layout in which there are two main layouts. 
One is an imageview and the second one is a scrollview. What I want is that the imageview is always kept on top of the scrollview. When I run the program the image goes back to the scrollview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_back"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/back" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:scrollbars="none" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <!-- Top linear layout -->

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_above_map"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="250dp" >

                        <com.shotwell.customviews.SmartViewPager
                            android:id="@+id/vp_slider"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                        <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                            android:id="@+id/dots"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="10dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
                        <!--
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:contentDescription="@null"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/bigimage" /
                        -->
>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_subtitle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                            android:text="Pan-Asian"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="normal" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_above="@id/tv_subtitle"
                            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/tv_subtitle"
                            android:text="Oka"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textSize="25sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_status"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tv_subtitle"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_subtitle"
                            android:background="@drawable/open_btn"
                            android:focusable="false"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Open"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="#878787" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:text="56"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:visibility="gone" />

                        <RatingBar
                            android:id="@+id/rb_rating"
                            style="@style/StarRatingBar"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:rating="5.0" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_desc_toggle"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Description"
                            android:textColor="#6A6A6A"
                            android:textSize="22sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_desc"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/dummy_list_text"
                            android:textColor="@color/dark_gray" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rl_map_holder"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp" >

                    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                        android:id="@+id/mapview"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_full_map"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:text="FullScreen"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <!-- bottom layout -->

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_below_map"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_address_city"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:padding="1dp"
                            android:text="Berlin Top, Fiapre Suryani"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_state_country"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:padding="1dp"
                            android:text="Brong Afoo, Ghana"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" >

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Phone no: "
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:textSize="12sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_phone"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text=" 024133556677"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" >

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Email: "
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:textSize="12sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_email"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="abc@yahoo.com"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" >

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="URL: "
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:textSize="12sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_url"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="www.newstate.com"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/ll_container_facility"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_toggle_facilities"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Facilities"
                            android:textColor="#6A6A6A"
                            android:textSize="22sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/ll_facilities"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical" />
                        <!--
                         <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/dummy_list_text"
                        android:textColor="@color/dark_gray" />
                        -->

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/ll_container_hours"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_toggle_timing"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Hours"
                            android:textColor="#6A6A6A"
                            android:textSize="22sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/ll_timings"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

It's the code of activity. which I am using. Resultant screen looks like this.[image: here is the image of output]

So in layouts it shows lines where I place my imageview but it won't show up.
I think maybe the scrollview is pushing back the imageview.
So how to put my imageview on top of the scrollview ?

Comment: inside your FrameLayout use Relative layout & inside that use your imageview & scrollview & use above & below tags

Comment: like Syed said, FrameLayout should be used for just 1 view inside it. Change it to Relative layout.

Comment: @OWADVL same thing happen in relative layout

Comment: its not possible you must be doing something wrong then in the architecture of you layout designing